# How do curried functions (with one argument) differ from methods?

Tags: scala

I'm having difficulty understanding how curried functions (with one argument) differ from normal methods. I tried to implement the latter with the former, but wasn't able to.

I have `Market` trait defined as follows:

```scala
package market {
  trait Market {
    def getBuyRate(currency: String): Double
    def getSellRate(currency: String): Double
  }
}
```

I have another `FakeMarket` trait that extends `Market` where I wanted to use currying to implement `getBuyRate` and `getSellRate`, as follows:

```scala
package market { 
  trait FakeMarket extends Market with Iterable[Double] {
    def getRate(factor: Double)(currency: String): Double = {
      factor * this.iterator.next()
    }
    def getBuyRate = getRate(1) _
    def getSellRate = getRate(1.02) _
  } 
}
```

Finally, I have `RandomFakeMarket` object that extends `FakeMarket`:

```scala
package market {
  object RandomFakeMarket extends FakeMarket {
    def iterator = new Iterator[Double] {
      def hasNext = true
      def next = 100.0
    }
  }
}
```

Having the types defined as such gives an error saying:

```
<console>:10: error: object creation impossible, since:
it has 2 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from object RandomFakeMarket, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
  def getBuyRate(currency: String): Double = ???
  def getSellRate(currency: String): Double = ???

       object RandomFakeMarket extends FakeMarket {
              ^
```

This seems odd to me because `FakeMarket` implements methods called `getBuyRate` and `getSellRate` of `String => Double` type.

I can get this to work if in `Market` I had done:

```
getBuyRate: String => Double
```

Why is this different from how I originally defined `getBuyRate`? Why should this be different when there's only one argument? Now it seems that the parent trait `Market` has to worry about how `getBuyRate` gets implemented (a normal function vs a curried function).

Comment: Why is this different? In Scala, methods and functions are different things (e.g., functions cannot take type parameters), and as such, you can't just use a function where a method is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much related to currying. `def method(p1: String, p2: String): String` is not equivalent to `def method: (String, String) => String` in scala. The difference between methods and functions is that methods support inheritance, so they need to know the method's **input and output**, which is not so obvious because of ambiguity:

`def get: String => Double` may be both `String -> Double` (iterpreted as unified member) and `() -> String -> Double` (interpreted as function). But in scala it's `Function1[String, Double]` or `() Function1[String, Double]`, which are simmilar in the meaning that there is no input. Unfortunatelly, `def get(): String => Double` makes no difference here (see examples below).

In other words, method may not have input parameters in scala (as it's may not be a pure function because of side effects), so it can't infer `(String)Double` from `String => Double` so your whole function becomes an output parameter. For example you could do `override def method: (String, String) => String` in some subclass - this will override method without parameters and with return type `(String, String) => String`, but not override the method with input `(String, String)` and return type `String`.

Another problem is that methods have different types than functions and may be only one-way converted by eta-expansion, so scala is a little bit incompatible with [UAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle) :

```
scala> def aaa(b: String): String = "aaa"
aaa: (b: String)String

scala> aaa _
res4: String => String = <function1>

scala> def aaa: String => String = (a: String) => "aa"
aaa: String => String

scala> def aaa()(b: String): String = "aaa"
aaa: ()(b: String)String

scala> def aaa(): String => String = (a: String) => "aa"
aaa: ()String => String
```

A bit more about methods vs functions: [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Comment: Thanks! So is there a way to do what I was trying to do earlier by reusing code to implement getBuyRate and getSellRate via currying? I guess for now I could just do `getBuyRate(x: String) = getRate(1.0, x)`

Comment: You're welcome). Sure, it will be `(String)Double`, so there is no problem with such polymorphism.